# Property 'map' does not exist on type '() => IterableIterator<number>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass `keys` as a React prop:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const keys: string[] = ["a", "b"];

function App({keys}: string[]) {
  return (
    <div>
      {keys.map((key: string) => (
        <li>{key}</li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App keys={keys} />, rootElement);
```

However, I get these errors:

> Property 'map' does not exist on type '() => IterableIterator'.
>
> Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '() => IterableIterator'.

Why is this, and how to fix it?

Live code: https://codesandbox.io/s/changing-props-on-react-root-component-forked-9lj9ye?file=/src/index.tsx:0-341

Comment: You're saying that `{keys}` is of type `string[]`, but that's not right; `{keys}` is of type `{keys: string}`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N72gDw).  It's unfortunate that you used a property of the same name as one that exists on arrays; if you had changed it to something else [you would have seen the issue more directly](https://tsplay.dev/NrDvlW).  Does this answer your question fully or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're typing your whole props as `string[]` instead of just `keys`. Embed `keys` prop in an object:

```js
function App({ keys }: { keys: string[]; }) {
  // ...
```

Or using an interface:

```js
interface AppProps {
  keys: string[];
}

function App({ keys }: AppProps) {
  // ...
```

Or a type:

```js
type AppProps {
  keys: string[];
}

function App({ keys }: AppProps) {
  // ...
```

To go further: [Differences Between Type Aliases and Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces)

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious, why an `interface` and not a `type`?

Comment: no real reason here, except inspiration of the moment ^^'
looking back, I would say because an interface is extendable... but types can somehow be extended using intersections so this is an option as well. I add it to the answer ;)